# Use header in multiple calls in the same scenario in Karate

Tags: karate

Having a feature with only one scenario with more than one http calls, I want to use the same host and headers for all calls. However, although I am able to set the url to apply for all calls, the header seems to only be applied in the first call and then reset. Does someone have any info on why this is happening and/or a suggestion on how to do it correctly (besides adding them in each call separately)?

Either by setting them in the `Background` or with a generic `Given`, url is used in both calls, but the header is only included in the first:
1)

```
Feature: sample

  Background:
  * header Content-Type = 'application/json' 
  * url http://localhost:8080

  Scenario: do multiple calls
    Given path /sample/
    When method GET
    Then status 200

    Given path /sample2/
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

2)

```
Feature: sample2

Given header Content-Type = 'application/json'
And url http://localhost:8080 

  Scenario: do multiple calls
    Given path /sample/
    When method GET
    Then status 200

    Given path /sample2/
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really really should read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure-headers

Just do:

```
Background:
  * configure headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

And there are many more options, just read the docs. Note that you typically never need to set the `Content-Type` because Karate does that automatically based on the request body.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was fixed when I added the "Header" informations I always use to the *"karate-config.js"*.

```
var accessToken = karate.callSingle("classpath:helpers/authentication.feature").accessToken
    
karate.configure("headers",{Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken})
```